# How to initialize a list of objects given only an interface sample?

Tags: go, interface, new-operator, typeof

I'm writing a database interface in Google Go. It takes `encoding.BinaryMarshaler` objects to save and saves them as []byte slices, and it loads data into `encoding.BinaryUnmarshaler` to return it:

```
func (db *DB) Get(bucket []byte, key []byte, destination encoding.BinaryUnmarshaler) (encoding.BinaryUnmarshaler, error) {
```

I want to implement being able to load an arbitrary length slice of `encoding.BinaryUnmarshaler`s in one go (for example "load all data from a bucket X"). I want the function to be able to load any number of data objects without knowing beforehand how many objects are to be loaded, so I don't expect the final user to pass me a slice to be filled. Instead, I take a `encoding.BinaryUnmarshaler` sample object to know what structures I'm dealing with:

```
func (db *DB) GetAll(bucket []byte, sample encoding.BinaryUnmarshaler) ([]encoding.BinaryUnmarshaler, error) {
```

The problem I ran into while coding this, is that I'm not sure how to initialize new instances of a given object, since I don't know what object I am dealing with, only what interface it conforms to. What I tried doing was:

```
tmp:=new(reflect.TypeOf(sample))
```

but that just caused an error.

How can I create a new object in go without knowing what structure it is, having an example object instead?

Comment: If you "don't know what object ... [you are] dealing with" then your're lost. That's something you need to know: Transmit, Take a look at how `gob` does it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New instance of struct from the type at runtime in GO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469177/new-instance-of-struct-from-the-type-at-runtime-in-go)

Comment: @kenfire this question was asked a month before the other one ;)

Comment: @ThePiachu Yes but you did not accept your answer so I couldn't do the other way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use `reflect.New` along with `reflect.TypeOf`:

```
tmp := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(sample))
```

http://play.golang.org/p/-ujqWtRzaP